# Understanding metadata in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, metadata

I'm currently writing some code for one of my classes involving distributed and parallel database processing. I'm doing horizontal fragmentation on some data and required to keep track of different pieces of data.

The professor recommends storing "metadata" to keep track of some basic computations. Is this as simple as creating another table and storing some basic information, or is there a much more efficient way of doing this?

Example:
I need to track ranges for min/max values of every table in my database. Should I store that information in an entirely new table or is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Example: I need to track ranges for min/max values of every table in my database. Should I store that information in an entirely new table or is there a better way of achieving this?

Yes, you should store min/max in a different table. Depending on your application, you might need more than one of those kinds of tables.

Each insert, update, or delete statement can change either or both of those values. Think about how you want to handle that. (Triggers, probably.)

**Terminology**

*Metadata* just means "data about other data", and min/max values for one or more columns in each table is arguably data about other data. But I've never seen such data called metadata. It's always either *summary* or *aggregate* data.

I think you'll find that when most DBAs and database developers use *metadata*, they're talking about system tables or the information_schema views that are built on top of system tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clears up some confusion for sure!